Non-autonomous system of two nonlinear ordinary differential equations with conditions
Consider the ODE system:
$$
\frac{df}{dx}= -\sqrt{g},\tag{1}
$$
$$
\frac{dg}{dx}= -\sqrt{x}f,\tag{2}
$$
where $f=f\left(x\right)$ and $g=g\left(x\right)$ are the functions on the interval $x\in\left[0,1\right]$. The following four conditions are also given:
$$
f\left(0\right)=F>0,\quad g\left(0\right)=G>0,\tag{3}
$$
$$
f\left(1\right)=0,\quad g\left(1\right)=0,\tag{4}
$$
where $F$ and $G$ are some positive constants.
I am interested in the following questions. Does there exist a continuous non-negative (i.e. $f\left(x\right)\geq0$ and $g\left(x\right)\geq0$, $\forall x\in\left[0,1\right]$) non-trivial solution of the system (1) and (2) consistent with the additional conditions (3) and (4) for some positive constants $F$ and $G$? If so, is there any way to express the exact value of the constants $F$ and $G$? The second question is the most interesting for me.
This issue originates from physics. Essentially, these equations are obtained from the one-dimensional diffusion problem. That is the reason why I am only interested in positive continuous solutions.
An approximate numerical solution can be found. We can consider the equations (1) and (2) with initial conditions (4) as a Cauchy problem. Solving it allows us to determine
the constants $F$ and $G$ from the conditions (3). Starting from the point $x=1$, one can obtain only a trivial solution. Thus, we should start from a point close to unity: $x=1-\epsilon$, $1\gg\epsilon>0$, and use the asymptotics as the initial conditions:
$$
f\left(1-\epsilon\right)\sim\frac{\epsilon^{3}}{36},\quad g\left(1-\epsilon\right)\sim\frac{\epsilon^{4}}{144},\qquad\epsilon\rightarrow+0.
$$
The numerical solutions presented in the figures below correspond to the following constants:
$$
F\simeq2.04\times10^{-2},\quad G\simeq2.35\times10^{-3}.
$$



There is the particular solution $f(x)=-\sqrt{14/5}x^{7/2}$, $g(x)=\sqrt{2/35}x^5$, but it does not satisfy your conditions.
Let $f=\exp(7\xi/2)u$, $g=\exp(5\xi)v$, $x=\exp(\xi)$ combine the equations and then let $5v+u=17/2 w(v)$ to get the Abel equation of the second kind
\begin{align}
ww'_v-w=-\frac{2}{17}v+\frac{4}{17^2}\sqrt{v},
\end{align}
as all nonlinear ODEs seem to reduce to... Unfortunately, there is only a known parametric solution for $ww'_v-w=-12/49 v+A\sqrt v$ to my knowledge.
